# Missing confirm button on multiselect image picker

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEXmH.png) I'm opening the gallery activity with ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent. I'm able to select multiple images but i miss the return button to the result activity. How i can implement that?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
```

Comment: Try using a different image picker app in your phone, this might be an issue with the gallery/image picker app.

Answer (score 0):

just open images with google photo:

```
   Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    getIntent.setType("image/*");
    getIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);


    getIntent.setType("image/*");
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/png"};
    getIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);

    Intent chooserIntent = null;

    if(isGooglePhotosInstalled(getApplicationContext())) {

        List<ResolveInfo> mApps = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(getIntent, 0);
        ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(3);
        String packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;
        getIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        getIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        getIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(getIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

    } else {

        //Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});

        pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        //getIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_IMAGE);

    }
```